# DNN Encrypted Profile Field

Tags: encryption, dotnetnuke

In DNN's site settings, I would like to store a user's credit card in their profile. Is there a way I can encrypt this data? Here is the code I use to pull user custom fields:

```
UserInfo theUser = new UserInfo
ProfilePropertyDefinition ppd = theUser.Profile.GetProperty(propName);
        if (ppd != null)
        {
            string v = ppd.PropertyValue;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(v))
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            return v;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

My advice would be don't even try.

There are a lot of other issues related to storing credit card information than just encrypting data. If you need help figuring out how to encrypt it, you're most likely much better off not storing it at all. PCI requirements are extremely strict and go much farther than data encryption to even specify the physical security measures that restrict access to the server the data is being stored on (encrypted or not).

Most payment gateways will take care of the heavy lifting for you as far as PCI requirements are concerned these days, and most people don't mind re-entering a credit card number each time they make a purchase. No reason to open yourself up to that liability, just make sure the data is transmitted securely then drop it for good.

You can read more about PCI requirements here: https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/.

Comment: Going through PCI auditing right now, I would also agree with @csearles11 on this one. If you absolutely need to store the info, doing it OUTSIDE of the DNN database would likely make the most sense.